# OpenGL setup for code::blocks "cannot find -lXxf86vm"

Tags: opengl, glut, codeblocks, freeglut

I'm working on setting up a dev environment for school.  We're going to be using GLUT to do graphics programming. I installed freeglut on Ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

I am going to be using code::blocks to write everything (as per the instructor's specifications) but when I try to build the default GLUT project in code::blocks, I get the following

```
Compiling: main.cpp 
Linking console executable: bin/Debug/glut_test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXxf86vm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It looks to me like I'm missing some dependency, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.  I have no idea what **-lXxf86vm** is, nor does Google or any other forum I can find.

Does anyone have ideas?

Update 1) this may have something to do with the fact that I have an Nvidia Optimus card in this laptop.

I tried running the default OpenGL project as well and it's throwing the following error

```
main: X server has no OpenGL GLX extension
```

I'm going to try installing bumblebee and see if that gets me anywhere

Answer (score 12):

> I have no idea what -lXxf86vm is, nor does Google or any other forum I can find.

This library provides an API for the XF86VidModeSwitch extension. XF86VidMode has been superseeded by XRandR, but freeglut may need it for its game mode support.

Just install the package "libxxf86vm-dev",

> Update 1) this may have something to do with the fact that I have an Nvidia Optimus card in this laptop.

No, that's not the reason for this particular library to be missing

> I tried running the default OpenGL project as well and it's throwing the following error

Well, you have not installed the NVidia-Drivers correctly.

Comment: Had the same issue with using Vulkan. Not sure if it's actually needed - just following [this tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment). The test program seems to build fine without it. Still linking with `-lXrandr` though.

Comment: @ワイきんぐ Vulkan is window system agnostic. If anything it's the windowing framework (GLFW or such) that might have this dependency.

Answer (score 5):

CodeBlocks always adds "Xxf86vm" to new GLUT projects.
I have no idea what it is, or why CodeBlocks adds it, (very annoying bug?) but you almost definitely DONT NEED IT!.

You can find it under: Project -> Build options... -> Linker settings.
Select your project name in the left pane, and it should appear under: "Link libraries".
Now, Just delete it from the list.  Your code should compile and run fine without it.

Comment: Thanks for this - I've reported it as a bug to Code::Blocks, as I'm pretty sure this is undesired. lXx86vm has been deprecated in favour of XRandR, and so doesn't ship with most systems.